# What appears to be a .net bug is happening after every recycle of a worker process. Only occurring when I'm using entity-framework

Tags: vb.net, entity-framework, windows-server-2003

I've written a vb.net project (.net 4) that seems to work perfectly on my windows 7 machine, and seems to work fine when published to a windows server 2003 server.

The issue comes after a few hours on my server, I get the infamous "Unable to load one or more of the requested types. Retrieve the LoaderExceptions property for more information". I haven't seen this problem at all when using visual studio.

Which seems to suggest to me that a reference to a dll / something is lost due to a cache process. Uploading **anything** to that folder temporally fixes the issue (including a test.txt file). Then after a few hours the issue returns.

I've turned off search indexing on the server and insured that the server is up to date.. but the error keeps on returning. (on investigation it returns every time the worker process recycles)

The issue only seems to appear on certain ascx files, these files reference an EntityDataSource that references an orders table.

Also I have attempted to get the LoaderExceptions and any other data with the following code:

```
Try
    OrdersTable.DataBind()
Catch ex As ReflectionTypeLoadException
    Response.Write(ex.Message)

    If (Not ex.InnerException Is Nothing) Then
        Response.Write(ex.InnerException.Message)

        Response.Write(ex.LoaderExceptions)
        For Each Parameter As DictionaryEntry In ex.Data
            Dim key As Object = Parameter.Key
            Dim value As Object = Parameter.Value
            Response.Write(key & ":" & value & "<br>\n")
        Next

    End If
    Response.End()
End Try
```

All that is written is the same error as before "Unable to load one or more of..."

New to the .net framework so any suggestions will be very much appreciated :).

Edit:
Stack trace attached.

```
[ReflectionTypeLoadException: Unable to load one or more of the requested types. Retrieve the LoaderExceptions property for more information.]
System.Reflection.RuntimeModule.GetTypes(RuntimeModule module) +0
System.Reflection.RuntimeModule.GetTypes() +4
System.Reflection.Assembly.GetTypes() +78
System.Data.Metadata.Edm.ObjectItemConventionAssemblyLoader.LoadTypesFromAssembly() +32
System.Data.Metadata.Edm.ObjectItemAssemblyLoader.Load() +25
System.Data.Metadata.Edm.AssemblyCache.LoadAssembly(Assembly assembly, Boolean loadReferencedAssemblies, ObjectItemLoadingSessionData loadingData) +160
System.Data.Metadata.Edm.AssemblyCache.LoadAssembly(Assembly assembly, Boolean loadReferencedAssemblies, KnownAssembliesSet knownAssemblies, EdmItemCollection edmItemCollection, Action1 logLoadMessage, Object& loaderCookie, Dictionary2& typesInLoading, List1& errors) +166
System.Data.Metadata.Edm.ObjectItemCollection.LoadAssemblyFromCache(ObjectItemCollection objectItemCollection, Assembly assembly, Boolean loadReferencedAssemblies, EdmItemCollection edmItemCollection, Action1 logLoadMessage) +316
System.Data.Metadata.Edm.ObjectItemCollection.ExplicitLoadFromAssembly(Assembly assembly, EdmItemCollection edmItemCollection, Action1 logLoadMessage) +53
System.Data.Metadata.Edm.MetadataWorkspace.ExplicitLoadFromAssembly(Assembly assembly, ObjectItemCollection collection, Action1 logLoadMessage) +93
System.Data.Metadata.Edm.MetadataWorkspace.LoadFromAssembly(Assembly assembly, Action1 logLoadMessage) +130
System.Web.UI.WebControls.EntityDataSourceView.ConstructContext() +585
System.Web.UI.WebControls.EntityDataSourceView.ExecuteSelect(DataSourceSelectArguments arguments) +76
System.Web.UI.DataSourceView.Select(DataSourceSelectArguments arguments, DataSourceViewSelectCallback callback) +21
System.Web.UI.WebControls.DataBoundControl.PerformSelect() +143
System.Web.UI.WebControls.BaseDataBoundControl.DataBind() +74
System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridView.DataBind() +4
System.Web.UI.WebControls.BaseDataBoundControl.EnsureDataBound() +66
System.Web.UI.WebControls.CompositeDataBoundControl.CreateChildControls() +75
System.Web.UI.Control.EnsureChildControls() +102
System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal() +42
System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal() +175
System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal() +175
System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal() +175
System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal() +175
System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal() +175
System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal() +175
System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) +2496
```

Comment: Dump the stack trace perhaps?

Comment: From the looks of it your problem is being 'resolved' by resetting the Application Pool.  Are you creating new ASPX/ASCX files at all during the run-time of your application?

Comment: Added the stacktrace, not sure what to make of it tbh.

Comment: Stopping then Starting the application pool, or recycling it does not resolve the problem. @Will

Comment: Sorry - I wasn't clear. Changing/adding files in your application directory generally results in the Application Pool being reset. Hence why uploading your test.txt file temporarily resolves the problem.

Comment: Oh and no not creating new aspx or ascx files at all during the run-time of my app.

Comment: If that were the case, then resetting my application pool would also temporarily resolve the problem surely? I think there is something else going on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end the solution that was easiest for me was to not do what was causing the bug to surface.

I now no longer bind any data at design time.

```
<asp:GridView ID="InvoiceTable" runat="server" AllowPaging="True" 
    AllowSorting="True" AutoGenerateColumns="False" DataKeyNames="Invoice_No" 
    DataSourceID="Invoices" CellPadding="4" ForeColor="#333333" 
    GridLines="None">
    ....[skiped for brevity]
</asp:GridView>
</div>
<asp:EntityDataSource ID="Invoices" runat="server" 
    ConnectionString="name=VetlabEntities1" DefaultContainerName="VetlabEntities1" 
    EnableFlattening="False" EntitySetName="SALES_MASTER">
</asp:EntityDataSource>
```

Becomes

```
<asp:GridView ID="InvoiceTable" runat="server" AllowPaging="True" 
    AllowSorting="True" AutoGenerateColumns="False" DataKeyNames="Invoice_No" 
    DataSourceID="Invoices" CellPadding="4" ForeColor="#333333" 
    GridLines="None">
    ....[skiped for brevity]
</asp:GridView>
```

---

```
Protected Sub BindInvoice()
    Dim db As New VetlabEntities1
    InvoiceTable.DataSource = db.SALES_MASTER
    InvoiceTable.DataBind()
End Sub
```

It also means that I now have to handle deleting / selecting etc. myself, which is a little irritating, however manageable.

Answer (score 0):

Have to tried to use the Fusion Log Viewer tool? It should give you some hints, although it's sometimes too verbose... Available here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e74a18c4

Comment: It looks to me like that's for development environments, this isn't happening in visual studio.

Comment: Have you looked at this connect post? http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/541962/unable-to-load-one-or-more-of-the-requested-types-connected-with-entitydatasource

Comment: This looks like a very useful link, thanks for posting. I had missed it in my searches. I will investigate further, of particular note is that recycling the worker process is causing the issue.